# Tracing each HTTP request from IE using C#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I want to make an windows application in .NET which will trace each HTTP request which is made from IE (Internet Explorer).

When i request for any URL that URL is going to be traced then i will compare that URL with my DB then if mathch found then my client/windows application will perform some task like making log/video recording etc.

for this i tried with Browser control in windows application but product owner is not ready with that solution, he want to use IE only.

So, is there any way to doing this?

Comment: As @SLaks, pointed out, you should look here: http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Extend-Fiddler/ExtendWithDotNet

Comment: @RePierre my tag is C#4.0,Fiddler is supports upto 3.5.other thing is what about licencing? Any other solutions....

Comment: Well, you can "borrow" some ideas from Fiddler: hook your application as a proxy for IE and process the requests you need.

Comment: @RePierre: Fiddler has nothing to do with IE; it operates through wininet.